# Creating a class on the client side of ServiceNow

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I am attempting to develop an API on the client side of service now to access a script include I made on the server side. The API is meant to be callable by client script and eliminate the need for my coworkers to have to use GlideAJAX. At the moment, I have a working script include, but I can't seem to figure out where to put the API such that client scripts are able to call it. Is it possible to do this? Or will my coworkers all have to learn both GlideAJAX and the variables I used in my script include?

Comment: GlideAjax ist exactly made for this purpose. There is no other API to execute Server side scripts from client in servicenow.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase. I'm not trying to execute server side code. The goal is to have a client side api that can be utilized. The api deals with glide ajax so that no one else has to. Where can I put the api so that it is client callable? I've tried UI scripts but they aren't letting me call them from client scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you make the ui script global and call it like this:

```
var myScript = new my_script_id(); //name of the ui script
myScript.myFunction();
```

Or you load it with ajax with [Scriptloader](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/newyork-application-development/page/app-store/dev_portal/API_reference/ScriptLoader/concept/c_ScriptLoaderAPI.html#c_ScriptLoaderAPI)

```
ScriptLoader.getScripts('my_script.jsdbx', function(){
    my_script.myFunction();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix! it turns out making it global was what it needed to get it working.